# React + Fetch API. Can't set response in setState

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I know this has been asked many times on this site but after going through SO questions related to this for the past 5 hours I have to throw in the towel and see if there's someone that can identify what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a fetch request in my react application that I am successfully receiving a response from but I am unable to store the response in my state. It seems to me that everything looks correct but when I attempt to store the response it simply does nothing. There are no console errors in the browser nor in my console that is running the react app. Currently the related code looks like this (Some things are slightly modified for privacy).

```
    loginSubmission = () => {
    fetch('https://genericsite.com/auth', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({"username": this.state.username, "password": this.state.password})
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {this.setState({response: res}, () => this.sendResponse())})
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  sendResponse(){
        console.log(this.state.response)
        let data = {response: this.state.response};
        this.props.receiveResponse(data);
  }
```

If I do it like how I have it below though I'm able to console.log the response with no issues but from what I was reading in a similar question there's something about console.log that forces it to complete the request so it can log the result.

```
    loginSubmission = () => {
    fetch('https://genericsite.com/auth', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({"username": this.state.username, "password": this.state.password})
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {console.log('res.response'})
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

That returns the following object:

```
{token: 'bigLongJumbledToken', idtoken: '', exp: 1655106045, username: 'myusername'}
exp: 1655106045
idtoken: ""
token: "bigLongJumbledToken"
username: "myusername"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

And my state in this component looks like so:

```
        this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        response: {}
    }
    this.userOnChange = this.userOnChange.bind(this);
    this.passOnChange = this.passOnChange.bind(this);
    this.loginSubmission = this.loginSubmission.bind(this);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

In this line: `.then(res => {this.setState({response: res}, () => this.sendResponse())})` you are calling the setState with two arguments, it should be only one. I think that you want to store the response in the state and also execute `sendResponse` function with the response data but, even after you fix the call of `setState` the function `sendResponse` will not receive the updated state because react will wait to finish the current executing function that is `.then()` before actually update the state.

You have two ways of do what (i guess) you are trying to do:

First: *use the response directly to call sendResponse*

Second: *use componentWillUpdate to call sendResponse after state updates*

I'll give an example of the first approach cause I think is the cleanest:

```js
.then(res => {
   this.setState({response: res})
   this.sendResponse(response)
})

sendResponse(res){ // expects response as a parameter
    console.log(this.state.response)
    // let data = {response: this.state.response}; // avoid this
    this.props.receiveResponse(res);
}
```

Comment: I tried both of those methods but neither of them had any effect.

Comment: From what I understand calling setState in the way that I did ensures that that function executes after the state is finished being set because setState is an asynchronous function.

Comment: @CyLewisHoward could you please post the shape of your initial state?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to update the original post with it right now.

Comment: I think you're on to something with the state. I restructured my code and am able to send it from the .then chain to the sendResponse function. It still does not store the data with setState but I'm able to console.log it from the function so at least that's a step in the right direction.

Is there maybe a conflict with the data type I'm choosing for my initial state vs what I'm trying to store perhaps?

Here's a JS Bin with the update to my code.
https://jsbin.com/muxakeliqo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @CyLewisHoward I don't think is related to the data but to the 'this'. I'm most used to functional component than to classes. You can try to put your console log inside the setState function to check if this.setState is executing something `this.setState(() => {console.log('INSIDE setState', res); return {response: res}})`